# Redirect the user to a specific submission after submitting a form

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I've written a basic forum model that allows users to create a post that others can respond to. After the user submits a form for a response to a forum post, the site displays a blank CommentForm, but instead, I want the user to be redirected to the unique forum post they responded to.
Here's what I have so far:

```
# views.py
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Forum
from .forms import CommentForm, ForumForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

# this is the view for the response form
@login_required
def newcomment(request):
    form = CommentForm
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit = True)
            post.save()
            form = CommentForm
    else:
        form = CommentForm
    return render(request, 'myapp/newcomment.html', {'form' : form})

# this is the view for a specific forum
def forumdetail(request, id):
    forum = get_object_or_404(Forum, pk = id)
    responses=[]
    responses.append(forum.comment_set.all())
 
    context={'forum' : forum,
              'responses' : responses}
    return render(request, 'myapp/forumdetail.html', context)
```

This is the webpage for the response form

```
<!-- myapp/newcomment.html -->
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}

<h2 style="font-family: Impact; letter-spacing: 3px;">New Comment</h2>
<table class = 'table'>
    <form method = "POST" class = "post-form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_table}}
</table>
<button type = 'submit' class = "save btn btn_default">
    Save
</button>
</form>



{% endblock %}
```

This is the webpage for a specific forum

```
<!-- myapp/forumdetail.html -->
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}

<h2 style="font-family: Impact; letter-spacing: 3px;">{{forum.topic}}</h2>
    <p style = "border-bottom: solid; border-width: 1px; padding-bottom: 15px;">{{forum.description}}
        <br>
        <small>Posted by {{forum.userID}} on {{forum.date_created}}</small>
    </p>


<button style = "background-color: gray;"> 
    <a href = "{% url 'newcomment' %}" style = "color: white;">Comment</a>
</button>
<h3>Comments:</h3>
    
<ul>
    <li style = "list-style-type: none;">
    {% for response in responses %}
        {% for objs in response %}  
        {% if objs.forum == forum %}
        {{ objs.response }}
        <br>
        <small style = "list-style-type: none; border-bottom: solid; border-width: 1px; padding-bottom: 15px;">
            {{ objs.userID }} on {{ objs.date_created }}</small>
            <br>
            <br>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    </li>
</ul>

{% endblock%}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you can do

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
def newcomment(request):
    form = CommentForm
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit = True)
            post.save()
            form = CommentForm
    else:
        form = CommentForm
    return redirect('forumdetail', post.forum.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this :-

from django.shortcuts import redirect

```
def newcomment(request,id):
    form = CommentForm
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit = True)
            post.save()
            form = CommentForm
    else:
        form = CommentForm
    return redirect('forumdetail',id=id)
```

urls.py

```
path ('newcomment/<int:id>/', views.newcomment,name='newcomment'),
```